# How i can make a distinct in leftJoin using adonis/node.js?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm trying to make a distinct in a leftJoin, but the `.distinct()` seems not work for my context.

I have this query:

```
const questions = Database
                                .query()
                                .select('book_unit_question.*')
                                .select('book_unit.unit')
                                .select('book_unit.sequence')
                                .select('books.id as book_id')
                                .select('book_unit_question_option.description as correct_answer_description_id')
                                .select('users.username')
                                .from('book_unit_question')
                                .leftJoin('book_unit_question_option', 'book_unit_question.id', 'book_unit_question_option.book_unit_question_id')
                                .distinct('book_unit_question.id')
                                .innerJoin('book_unit', 'book_unit.id', 'book_unit_question.book_unit_id')
                                .innerJoin('books', 'books.id', 'book_unit.book_id')
                                .innerJoin('users', 'book_unit_question.user_id', 'users.id')
                                .where('books.id', '=', request.params.id)
```

But when i get my results, i have repetead `book_unit_question.id` :

```
0: {id: 11, book_unit_id: 2, question_form: "Texto", option_form: "Texto",…}
1: {id: 11, book_unit_id: 2, question_form: "Texto", option_form: "Texto",…}
2: {id: 11, book_unit_id: 2, question_form: "Texto", option_form: "Texto",…}
3: {id: 12, book_unit_id: 2, question_form: "Texto", option_form: "Texto", type_answer: "Aberta",…}
```

I need only:

```
0: {id: 11, book_unit_id: 2, question_form: "Texto", option_form: "Texto",…}
1: {id: 12, book_unit_id: 2, question_form: "Texto", option_form: "Texto", type_answer: "Aberta",…}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `distinct()` without parameters:

```
const questions = Database
  .from('book_unit_question')
  .select('book_unit_question.*', 'book_unit.unit', 'book_unit.sequence', 'books.id as book_id', 'book_unit_question_option.description as correct_answer_description_id', 'users.username')
  .distinct()
  .leftJoin('book_unit_question', 'book_unit_question.id', '=', 'book_unit_question_option.book_unit_question_id')
  .join('book_unit', 'book_unit.id', '=', 'book_unit_question.book_unit_id')
  .join('books', '=', 'books.id', 'book_unit.book_id')
  .join('users', '=', 'book_unit_question.user_id', 'users.id')
  .where('books.id', '=', request.params.id);
```

Docs [here](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/query-builder#distinct)