# compare two comlumns with query builder adonis.js

Tags: knex.js, adonis.js

This is with La-ravel ,please how to do it with Adonis query builder?

```
{$data = DB::table("items")
        ->where Column('created_at','updated_at')
        ->get();}
```

Comment: Hi @Khalilkadri - welcome to Stack Overflow.  Does this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59056620) help you?

Comment: Thanks for ur help!
Unfortunately It didn't work